# Does fluid motion follow some periodic function?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, waves, oscillators

I have heard of oscillations (i.e. simple harmonic motions) where a particle repeats its motion after a period of time, due to the restoring force acting opposite to the displacement and proportional to it. Does the same apply for a liquid (especially during streamline flow)?

Can we represent it as $$y= A \sin (k x - \omega t)$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question? The question s unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deterministic motion falls in to two categories: periodic motion and chaotic motion; I'll try to provide a brief overview. In physics, we usually discuss the evolution of dynamical systems in terms of differential equations. Consider a simple pendulum of length $l$. For small oscillations, the angle of the pendulum obeys the equation

$$
\ddot{\theta} + {g\over l}\theta=0.
$$

The solution to this is a simple sine wave (i.e., $\theta(t) = \theta_0 \cos(\sqrt{g/l} t)$}.

Now, lets add a damping term $\beta \dot{\theta}$, and a driving force $\gamma \cos(\omega t)$, the differential equation to solve is now:

$$
\ddot{\theta} + \beta \dot{\theta}+ {g\over l}\theta=\gamma \cos(\omega t).
$$

Even when we complicate things to this point, the motion of the pendulum is still *periodic*. To stray from the realms of periodic behavior, we need to introduce a *non-linearity*.

Let us assume the pendulum has a stiffness to it that obeys a cubic version of Hooke's law. We then have the following equation
$$
\ddot{\theta} + \beta \dot{\theta}+ {g\over l}\theta + \alpha \theta^3=\gamma \cos(\omega t).
$$

This equation goes by the name of the *Duffing Equation* and it is one of the simplest differential equations that exhibits *chaotic behaviour*. For certain parameters in the Duffing equation, the motion is very aperiodic. Although the motion is deterministic, the behavior can appear random.

The (incompressible) Navier-Stokes equations describing fluid flow can be written as
$$
{\displaystyle {\frac {\partial \mathbf {u} }{\partial t}}+(\mathbf {u} \cdot \nabla )\mathbf {u} -\nu \nabla ^{2}\mathbf {u} =-\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla p .}
$$

While this equation does admit periodic solutions in particular expansions, solutions can exhibit chaotic behaviour as the second term is *nonlinear* in ${\bf u}$. It is believed that it is this term that is responsible for the phenomenon of turbulence.

So in conclusion, if the fluid obeys the Navier-Stokes equation, then there is no periodic function that can describe its chaotic behavior.

We can, however, perform perturbation theory and *linearize* the Navier-Stokes equation by assuming the form ${\bf u} = {\bf u}_0 +{\bf u}_1$, and neglecting terms of order $\mathcal{O}({\bf u}_1^2)$. The result is

$$
{\partial {\bf u}_1 \over \partial t} + ({\bf u}_0 \cdot \nabla){\bf u}_1 + ({\bf u}_1 \cdot \nabla){\bf u}_0 - \nu\nabla^2 {\bf u}_1 = {-1 \over \rho}\nabla p_{1}.
$$

This *linear* differential equation will admit *periodic* solutions for ${\bf u}_1$. However, the validity of the solutions requires $|{\bf u}_1|/|{\bf u}_0| \ll 1$. The results of linear perturbation theory are often very useful for determining the properties of a fluid around an equilibrium.

Comment: Can the nonlinear equation be approximately linearized in some limiting situation? Does that help our cause?

Answer (score 3):

If the oscillations are small enough that the governing differential equation may be reasonably approximated with a wave equation, almost every system in equilibrium will exhibit the pattern of motion you've described. It's often a terrible approximation for fluid systems.

Comment: In some situations it's fine, like the propagation of sound waves far from their source

Comment: @kleingordon Indeed. That's why I qualified the statement with the word often. Should I re-write that?